# Image decomposition using wavelet

Tags: matlab, wavelet

I used the code below to decompose my image in wavelet. but I want the detailed coefficients ('h','v' and 'd') to be one file and not as 3 different images.

```
X=imread('snow.tif');
close all
clf
image(X)
colormap('default')
axis ('image'); set(gca,'XTick',[],'YTick',[]); title('Original')
pause

dwtmode('sym')
wname = 'bior4.4'

t = wtree(X,2,'bior4.4');
plot(t)
pause
close(2)

[wc,s] = wavedec2(X,5,wname);

a1 = appcoef2(wc,s,wname,1);         
h1 = detcoef2('h',wc,s,1);           
v1 = detcoef2('v',wc,s,1);           
d1 = detcoef2('d',wc,s,1);           

a2 = appcoef2(wc,s,wname,2);
h2 = detcoef2('h',wc,s,2);
v2 = detcoef2('v',wc,s,2);
d2 = detcoef2('d',wc,s,2);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "one file"?  Do you want them stacked horizontally or vertically?  As different channels (like in RGB?).  Please clarify.

Comment: either horizontally or vertically, both will do. and one file means the variables to be stored together.

Comment: In that case, you can maybe make the components a 3 dimensional matrix.  Try doing this: `matrix1 = cat(3, h1, v1, d1); matrix2 = cat(3, h2, v2, d2);`  This way each decomposition is a 3D matrix. The `h` components are your first channel, `v` components your second and `d` components your third.